# How to get the registration info from the $registration? (eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The user can access a page where appears a list with his next registrations in conferences, that is, registrations in conferences that have not happened yet. For each registration done by the user, if that registration has not yet been paid, that is, the status column of that registration in the registrations table is "I" (incomplete) it appears the link "Pay":

```
@foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
    @if(!empty($nextRegistration->conference || !empty($nextRegistration->conference->start_date)))
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <h5>{{optional($nextRegistration->conference)->name}}</h5>
             @if ($nextRegistration->status === 'I')
                    <a href="{{route('conferences.showPaymentPage',
                        ['id' => $nextRegistration->conference->id,
                        'slug' => $nextRegistration->conference->slug,
                        'regID'=> $nextRegistration->id])}}"
                        class="btn btn-primary ml-2"> Pay  
                    </a>
            @endif
        </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

When the user clicks in Pay he should be redirected to a payment page like "http://proj.test/conference/2/conference-title/payment/registration/6", where 6 is the registration id that the user wants to pay and "2" is the conference id, so the user is paying a registration concerning the conference with id "2".

In the registration payment page should appear a summary of the registration. For example, if a user did a registration in a conference with 3 tickets/registration types, 1 of the type "general" and 2 of the type "plus", it should appear a summary like:

```
Title of the conference (ex: Conference test)
Date of the conference

Registration Type   Quantity         Price     Subtotal
 general             1            0.00 €      0.00$
 plus                2            1.00 €      2.00$
```

So I have this route for when the user clicks in the Pay button:

```
Route::get('/conference/{id}/{slug?}/payment/registration/{regID}', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@showPaymentPage',
    'as'   =>'conferences.showPaymentPage'
]);
```

And in the `showPaymentPage()` I get the registration  of the PaymentController I get the registration that the user wants to pay with "`$registration = Registration::find($regID);`":

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
   public function showPaymentPage($id = "", $slug = "", $regID){
      $registration = Registration::find($regID);

//dd($registration->conference) shows Conference {#282 ▼ #fillable: array:18 [▶]...}
//dd($registration->customer) shows User {#282 ▼ #fillable: array:13 [▶]...}

    }
}
```

**Doubt:**

Do you know how from the $registration get the necessary info to show the registration info like in the above summary?

**Relevant tables structure for the question:**

```
Registration table:

    id, status, conference_id, main_participant_id

Registration Types table:

    id, name, price, confernece_id

Conference table:

    id, name, date, organizer_id

Participant table:

id, registration_id, registration_type_id, name, surname
```

**Relevant models for the question:**

User model:

```
 class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        public function conferences(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Conference', 'organizer_id');
        }
        public function registrations(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Registration','main_participant_id');
        }
    }
```

Conference model:

```
class Conference extends Model
{
    public function organizer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'organizer_id');
    }
    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }
    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'conference_id');
    }
}
```

Registration Type model:

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }

    // a registration can have many participants
    public function participants(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
    }
}
```

Registration model:

```
class Registration extends Model
{
    // a registration has one user that do the registration
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'main_participant_id', 'id');
    }

    // a registration can have many participants
    public function participants(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
    }

    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }

    public function payment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Payment');
    }
}
```

Participant model:

```
class Participant extends Model
{

    // a participant belongs to a registration
    public function registration(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
    }

    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\RegistrationType');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your schema is a bit odd. By the looks of URI it seems that you are requesting info on specific "Registration", but you are displaying all of user's registrations.
For the sake of clarity you should use something like `http://proj.test/conference/{conference_id}/registration/status`.

Your problem is that you are missing `registration_type_id` column ub `registration` table. There is no way to connect user with registration type.

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with the structure of the participants table and the Participant model. The participants table has the registration_type_id. And the user that did the registration is the "main_participant_id" of the registrations table.

Comment: A user can do a registration in a conference and register him and other participants but the user that did the registration is stored in the registrations table using the "main_participant_id" column.

Comment: The url ""http://proj.test/conference/2/conference-title/payment/registration/6"" is to redirect the user to the payment page that corresponds to the registration with id "6" and that corresponds to a registration in a conference with id "2".

Comment: I understood that, but as first registration ID is enough, because there is relation between registration and conference table. It isn't big issue, but you should always strive to make code/ui simpler ;)